send keypad stroke 0198 to word application inside AddIn
I write Office Word addin using Add-In-Express.
I want to add some letters and for one of the letters i want to send alt-0198 keypad stoke.
in hebrew it should add 3 dots under the letter.
how do i send this combination to the WordApp?
I treid to use use keybd_event but it did not work

just use :
   keybd_event(VK_LMENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_LMENU, 0), 0, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD0, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD0, 0), 0, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD0, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD0, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD1, 0), 0, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD1, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD1, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD9, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD9, 0), 0, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD9, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD9, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD5, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD5, 0), 0, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_NUMPAD5, MapVirtualKey(VK_NUMPAD5, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_LMENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_LMENU, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

this will add :
חטף קמץ
תֳ
aly-pad 0195
to the Hebrew Letter
